# Cascading: Java tutorial for the Impatient, Part1 : Gradle build fails

Tags: build.gradle, cascading

When building part1 of the tutorial on CentOS 6.5,java version "1.7.0_51" I get Gradle error:

***You can't change configuration 'providedCompile' because it is already resolved!***

[localhost part1]$ gradle clean jar

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file '/home/test/wks/Cascading/Java/Impatient/part1/build.gradle' line: 43
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':part1'.

  > You can't change configuration 'providedCompile' because it is already resolved!
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

What may be wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This is a shot in the dark but I had the same issue (different project) and searching is how I landed here on SO.
In my case the error was caused by a '+=' in my script that was adding a single element to a collection.
The other response to the OP's issue from another forum is simply to use Gradle 1.12.

HTH.

This answer has a wider scope than the "tutorial" build, and also applicable to those who land here while searching for a solution to the actual error reported by the build.

From [Gradle Community Forums](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/custom_provided_configuration_not_working_with_gradle_2_0_rc2_in_multi_project_mode):

Gradle 2 updated to Groovy 2.3, which no longer supports the use of += for adding a single element to a collection. So instead of scopes.PROVIDED.plus += configurations.provided it's now scopes.PROVIDED.plus += [configurations.provided]. (The other uses of '+=' are OK.)

Answer (score 3):

AS JavaBrewer proposed, if you compile this against a version of gradle bigger than 2.0 you need to change the file: common/providedCompile.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'maven'

configurations {
  providedCompile
}

sourceSets {
  main.compileClasspath += [configurations.providedCompile]
}

task mappings {
  conf2ScopeMappings.addMapping( 0, configurations.providedCompile, Conf2ScopeMappingContainer.PROVIDED )
}

idea {
  module {
    scopes.PROVIDED.plus += [configurations.providedCompile]
  }
}

javadoc {
  classpath += configurations.providedCompile
}

eclipse {
    classpath{
        plusConfigurations += [configurations.providedCompile]
    }
}
```

Pay attention that since version 2.0 in order to add an element to a collection with the operator +=, you have to append another collection. you achieve this by adding []